# Is it impossible to pass a instance variable as default of a method keyword?

Tags: python, class, oop, instance, self

This will not work:

```
class myClass:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def methodA(self, name=self.name):
        print(f"Hello {name}!")

myInstance = myClass("Frank")
```

Because:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Questions

1. Why is that? Is `self.name` not already defined at the initialization of the class?
2. Is there a way to have `name` defined at initialization of a class instance while also being able to changing its value when calling specific methods at the same time? I don't want to always change its value with a separate line (e.g. like so: `myInstance.name = "Peter"`) before I call a method. And, I also don't want to be forced to pass it on using a keyword (e.g. like so: `def methodB(self, name=name_typed_when_calling_method)` every time I call a method that uses that variable.

Comment: you can directly access `self.name` within your methodA since it's a "self" method, you do not need to pass in the name.

Comment: Yes, you can't define a default value using another parameter (default values are evaluated **at definition time**).

Comment: No, you cannot do that. However you can make the default value `None` and check for that value in the method (and use `self.name` when it is).

Comment: I see, evaluation at definition time explains my first question. Regarding the second, is there no other way than what @martineau suggested? Checking every time whether the keyword is still `None` at the beginning of each method seems as verbose/tedious as manually changing it  (e.g. `myInstance.name = "Peter"`) before calling any method.

Comment: It's the idiomatic way that default arguments are handled in these cases. It isn't semantically the same as modifying the object *at call time* though

Comment: Michel: No, I don't think there's a workaround because the default value you want to use can't be determined until an instance is created (and default values are determined **at definition time** as @juanpa.arrivillaga said).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` is not defined when the default argument is evaluated, which is when the method is *defined*. It's just a function parameter, which gets bound to an argument when the method is *called*.

What you need to do is use a sentinel (like `None`) as the default, and check for that inside the body of the method where `self` *is* defined.

```
class myClass:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def methodA(self, name=None):
        if name is None:
            name = self.name
        print(f"Hello {name}!")

myInstance = myClass("Frank")
```